# add Webview start url to sharedpreference for webview

Tags: android, webview, sharedpreferences

I'm still learning Java. I'm trying to get use SharedPreferences to set the url in my WebView, so that I can set the page that is displayed the next time the app starts up.
And trying to set/change the value using a menu.

Here is what I have so far:

```
  public class test extends Activity {

public static final String PREFS_NAME = "SharedPreferences";

public static final String PREF_STRING = "http://www.google.com";
private SharedPreferences mPrefs;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mPrefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    webview = new WebView(this) {

    };
    webChromeClient = new WebChromeClient() {

    };

    webview.setWebChromeClient(webChromeClient);
    webview.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
    setContentView(webview);

    /** Load the Browser Settings */
    webview.loadUrl(PREF_STRING);

    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("StartPage", 0);
    settings.getString("PREF_STRING", "http://www.google.com");

}

/** Begin Globals */
public WebView webview;
public WebChromeClient webChromeClient;
public WebViewClient webViewClient;

/*** define menu options */
private static final int MENU_PAGE1 = 1;
private static final int MENU_PAGE2 = 2;

/*** menu items */
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.add(0, MENU_PAGE1, 0, "Set page 1 to show when app is started");
    menu.add(0, MENU_PAGE2, 0, "Set page 2 to show when app is started");

    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case MENU_PAGE1:
        Editor e = mPrefs.edit();
        e.putString(PREF_STRING, "http://www.yahoo.com");
        e.commit();

        Toast.makeText(this, "Page 1 is set!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return true;
    }
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case MENU_PAGE2:
        Editor e = mPrefs.edit();
        e.putString(PREF_STRING, "http://www.ask.com");
        e.commit();

        Toast.makeText(this, "Page 2 is set!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return true;

    }

    return false;

}
}
```

So close yet, so far... Any hints or ideas?

Comment: you want get url from sharepref.. and open in webview?

Comment: @CapDroid Kind of,  I would like it to store my selection in the menu and then display the page I select after I restart the phone and app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try this:

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mPrefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    webview = new WebView(this) {

    };
    webChromeClient = new WebChromeClient() {

    };

    webview.setWebChromeClient(webChromeClient);
    webview.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
    setContentView(webview);

    /* Load the last saved preference. */
    webview.loadUrl(mPrefs.getString(PREF_STRING, "http://www.google.com"));

}
```

Comment: "webview.loadUrl(mPrefs.getString(PREF_STRING, "http://www.google.com"));" Did it, Thanks!